# Preserving case of HTTP headers with curl

Tags: curl, http-headers

I'm trying to use curl to send a HTTP request with custom headers (`curl http://example.com -H "Foo: bar"`), and I'm finding that when the header arrives, it has been lower-cased, by curl (the above `Foo` header is received as `foo: bar`)

How to preserve the case of headers in a request?

Comment: HTTP headers are *case insensitive* so the case **must not** matter to anyone speaking HTTP proper...

Comment: @DanielStenberg Except not everyone actually follows specs, which is the whole point of this question, since if you want (need?) to interact with someone who doesn't follow the specs, then you need to not follow them yourself, in the same specific way they don't.   HTTP earlier than HTTP 2 was at least case preserving, and as such, if you tell curl to use HTTP 1.1 it will respect the case of the headers you tell it to set.

Comment: HTTP was never "case preserving". It was always just *case insensitive* but some clients would preserve or enforce a special casing. curl for example typically passes on the casing used by the user - unless for HTTP/2 which is lowercase by spec.

Comment: as I already said - not every server actually follows the spec. It seems kinda silly that a client library would not have an option to signify it was talking to such a broken server. feature request?

Comment: modern curl doesn't do this :) (at least version 7.80.0, released 2021-11-10 doesn't do this)

Answer (score 47):

Try forcing curl to use HTTP/1.1 - it defaults to HTTP/2, the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2) for which states that headers must be in lower case.

```
curl http://example.com --http1.1 -H "Foo: bar"
```

Comment: Take my upvote, I've been struggling on this issue for days.