# `curl` applying lowercase to headers

Tags: curl, wget

There is a website that I need to scrape just a single page and I discovered it blocks access from `curl` but allows from `wget`. Making exactly the same request (same headers, cookies, same origin IP...) has different results: `curl` gets blocked while `wget` does not. Surely, there is some fingerprinting being used.

After using a reverse proxy to check what was going on, I discovered that `curl` lowercases automatically some headers. For example, despite using `-H 'User-Agent: YYY'` the request will be made like `user-agent: YYY` the same happens with `-H 'Accept: */*'` which becomes `accept: */*`. This small difference makes `curl` "stand out" and easier to fingerprint (I know there are other ways to fingerprint requests, like checking SSL cyphers available, timing from the hand shake... but this is not the case here).

I cant find a way to stop `curl` from converting every header name (not the value, only the name) to lowercase. Do you have any idea if there is any option that allows me to stop that?

Comment: Aside: Thank you for providing a practical use case for the request; cuts off a lot of "if the server doesn't see them as equivalent it's buggy" potential sidebars at the pass. Not an aside: Is this only for the command-line curl tool, or would a libcurl-centric answer be accepted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserving case of HTTP headers with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067796/preserving-case-of-http-headers-with-curl)

Comment: (`DYNHDS_OPT_LOWERCASE`, in particular, is unconditionally set for http/2 headers... for reasons the duplicate suggested explains, and which given that duplicate's rationale probably aren't unique to or much of a fingerprint of curl)